# replacing a match without crossing some other match

Tags: regex

Right now I am using `{{.+?}}` (in Python with re, for what it's worth) to match `{{text}}`, but the issue is that sometimes this occurs: `{{ text {{text}} text }}`. In the regular expression literature, I have seen ways of solving this, but I couldn't get it to work. Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

EDIT: The goal is to have it select all, not just the middle part.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a negative character class, like so:

```
\{\{[^\}\{]+\}\}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a negative lookahead: `{{(?:(?!{{).)+?}}`

[EDIT]

If they could be nested at most one level deep, as in `{{ text {{text}} text }}`, you could use:

```
{{[^{}]*(?:{{[^{}]*}}[^{}]*)*}}
```

If they could be arbitrary levels deep, you need a recursive regex, which Python's re module doesn't support. However, the regex module here does: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Comment: Don't the braces need to be escaped?  Won't they get confused with a regex quantifier?

Comment: It isn't correct as a quantifier, so it defaults to being a literal. (I did test it before posting!)

Comment: I don't doubt it.  Just curious.

Comment: It's a good question, though.  Some regex flavors require you to escape the braces anyway, whether they would form a valid quantifier or not.  Or the left brace, at least.

Comment: Re the braces, the OP did say it was for Python. @Cenoc: I want to repeat `(?!{{).`. Without the `(?:...)`, the quantifier would apply only to the `.`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use regex pattern

```
\{{2}(?:[^{}]+|(?<!\})\}(?!\})|(?<!\{)\{(?!\{)|\{{2}\}{2})\}{2}
```